# Auth between a website and self-owned API

Tags: authentication

This has probably been asked before, so a preemptive apology from me.

I built a site and I built an API.  The API will also be used by a mobile app in the future.  I own both so I'm pretty sure two and three legged OAuth aren't for me.  The API has parts that are accessible to the world and other parts that are protected and require a user account.  To keep things simple I've just gone with a https + Basic Auth solution (for now).  It's all fine and good when testing requests manually to the API (I didn't write tests because I'm a bad person), things work as expected and Basic Auth is fine.

I'm trying to solve the flow of a user logging in with plaintext user and password, send that to the API to authenticate, the API just needs to say yes or no, yet all requests from the site (on behalf of a user) to the API should be signed in some way with their credentials for when they want to POST/GET/PUT/DEL one of the protected resources.

Out of all of the auth resources I've read I'm still confused as to what scheme to use.  Storing the plaintext password on the site side so that I can base 64 encode it and send it over the wire seems bad, but it looks like that's what I'd have to do.  I've read of digest auth but I'm not sure I get it.  Any and all advice is welcome.

Comment: How about a token? When they authenticate you generate a token and store that. Have it expire after a certain amount of time. You would have to support this on the API side.

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about this.  I'm still curious as to what best practice is.  This problem has been solved already, so what are the big names doing?  Also, would this solution stand on it's own without SSL?  Does any?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how I would handle this case;

1. POST the username and password as a plain text to your api using HTTPS of course.
2. Then validate it to your database, the best algorithm used nowadays to salt password is **bcrypt**.
3. If the user is not valid return 401, or whatever.
4. If the user is valid, return a JWT token with his profile signed with a Public Key algorithm.
5. Your fron-end knows the public key so it can decode the JWT but it can't generate a new one.
6. For every request that needs authentication, you attach an `Authentication` header, with `Bearer [JWT]`
7. A middleware in the backend reads this header and validate it with the private key.

Don't be affraid of JWT there are plenty of implementations for every language and framework and is easier than you might think. A lot of applications are already using JWT already even Google.

[Auth0](https://www.auth0.com) is an authentication broker that can validate against any identity provider or custom database, and returns JWTs. It provides a clientID that can be used to decode the profile in the front end and a secret to validate the tokens in the backend as well as [client side library](https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js) to do this.

**Disclaimer: I work for auth0.**

**Update:** Since you mention node.js and express in comments I will give an example in this technology.

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');

var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');  //https://npmjs.org/package/node-jsonwebtoken
var expressJwt = require('express-jwt'); //https://npmjs.org/package/express-jwt

var secret = "this is the secret secret secret 12356";


var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
  this.use(express.urlencoded());
  this.use(express.json());
  this.use('/api', expressJwt({secret: secret}));
});

//authentication endpoint
app.post('/authenticate', function (req, res) {
  //validate req.body.username and req.body.password
  //if is invalid, return 401
  var profile = {
    first_name: 'John',
    last_name: 'Foo',
    email: 'foo@bar.com',
    id: 123
  };

  var token = jwt.sign(profile, secret, {
    expiresInMinutes: 60*5
  });

  res.json({
    token: token
  });
});

//protected api
app.get('/api/something', function (req, res) {
  console.log('user ' + req.user.email + ' is calling /something');
  res.json({
    name: 'foo'
  });
});

//sample page
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('listening on http://localhost:8080');
});
```

This is an express application with one endpoint that validates username and password. If the credentials are valid it returns a JWT token with the full profile, with expiration 5 hours.

Then we have an example endpoint in `/api/something` but since I've a express-jwt middleware for everything on `/api` it requires a Authorization: Bearer header with a valid token. The middleware not only validates the token but also parses the profile and put it on req.user.

How to use this client-side? This is an example with jquery:

```
//this is used to parse the profile
function url_base64_decode(str) {
  var output = str.replace("-", "+").replace("_", "/");
  switch (output.length % 4) {
    case 0:
      break;
    case 2:
      output += "==";
      break;
    case 3:
      output += "=";
      break;
    default:
      throw "Illegal base64url string!";
  }
  return window.atob(output); //polifyll https://github.com/davidchambers/Base64.js
}
var token;

//authenticate at some point in your page
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/authenticate',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            username: 'john',
            password: 'foo'
        }
    }).done(function (authResult) {
        token = authResult.token;
        var encoded = token.split('.')[1];
        var profile = JSON.parse(url_base64_decode(encoded));
        alert('Hello ' + profile.first_name + ' ' + profile.last_name);
    });
});

//send the authorization header with token on every call to the api
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        if (!token) return;
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    }
});

//api call
setTimeout(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/something',
    }).done(function (res) {
        console.log(rest);
    });
}, 5000);
```

First, I've an authenticate call with the username and password, I can decode the profile in the JWT to get the user profile and I also save the token to use in every request later on.

The ajaxSetup/beforeSend trick adds the header for every call. So, then I can make a request to /api/something.

As you can imagine this approach doesn't use cookies and sessions so it works out of the box in CORS scenarios.

I'm a big fan of passport.js and I've contributed a lot of adapters and fixes for some other adapter but for this particular case I wouldn't use it.

Comment: So, I think I've read about this type of flow, but I'm still unclear on the details of implementation.  Does this flow have a common name?  With public/private key systems, like SSH, I generate a public key and literally send (copy/paste) to the other entities I want to share it with.  So would I literally be generating some sort of random hash and then dropping it into the backend of my site?  How do I generate it's counterpart?

Comment: Right now the API and site are using express with the [passportjs](http://passportjs.org/) module, it seems pretty comprehensive so I'm assuming it supports what you're talking about?  So, I guess I'm confused as to how to actually go about generating these two keys, and whether or not this is a common flow that already has solutions built.  I'd rather understand this under the hood for myself rather than outsource it, as it seems like it should not be as hard as it is for me.

Comment: I will improve my answer, with node js modules.

Comment: Hey, thanks a bunch.  This works.  I ended up removing passportjs and replacing it with the implementation above.  Does this method require https?  How secure is it, exactly?

Comment: You require HTTPS to authenticate in the endpoint where you send the username and the plain password. Even if the JWT is signed, the  profile in the JWT is just "encoded" not encrypted.

Comment: Hi, sorry to return after so long.  Just to clarify, does the fact that it's encoded and not encrypted mean that this is not safe to expose to the client?

Comment: Hi, it's really nice answer. From what I understood, expressJwt guard out api's and basically will validate the token. But I'd like to go a step further, and associate a token with app specific scopes, in similar way that one would do it in OAuth2.0. So for example, I would like to assign a write, read etc. scopes and have the expressJwt check is the user's token has the required scopes to access an API endpoint. I hope my question is clear

Comment: @ppoliani that's a fantastic question. Can you open a new question on stackoverflow so I can elaborate my answer,

Comment: @JoséF.Romaniello http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240339/nodejs-oauth2-0-pronciples

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about a similar scenario lately; here's what I did:

1. SSL + Basic Auth
2. In the DB (on the API side), generate a random salt (per user), and save the salt and the hashed (password + salt). When a request arrives, throw on the salt and hash it, then compare to what you've saved
3. Send the password in plaintext - you are using SSL so I think this is okay (this is the part I am most uncertain of)

I don't have a great reason for recommending this but in case you have a reason to use it:

.4. Attach a timestamp to every request and have them expire after a couple of minutes.

The reason you should save salted-and-hashed passwords in your DB is in case someone steals your DB.

Basically I'm putting a lot of faith into SSL, and what I've read tells me that's okay.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This seems homegrown though - what's the best practice?  That's what I'm after.  I'm imagining a solution that could exist fairly securely without SSL and not require me to send the password in plaintext more than once.

Comment: Hmmm I see what you're saying. If you want to stay away from SSL then definitely look at digest authentication to avoid sending the password in plaintext. I once wrote a small program to make a query to AWIS... I seem to have deleted it from github but I will try and find the Amazon documentation for you. You use your password to hash the message before sending it, and then the message and hash are sent together to the server which recomputes the hash with your stored password. No encryption, if I remember correctly... let me see if I can find it for you.

Comment: Ok I found this, if you look around it should help! http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AlexaWebInfoService/latest/