# NodeJS OAuth2.0 principles

Tags: node.js, security, oauth-2.0

Recently I was working on a nodeJS project and I was thinking how to go about and implement the security module of my mobile application. I had a previous experience from OAuth 2.0 protocol which I used in C# projects in the past.

In .NET there are two nice open source project

1. https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3
2. https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.AuthorizationServer

The former is an Identity Provider supporting federated authentication and the later is an OAuth 2.0 provider.

So I decided to employ the same security infrastructure for my nodeJS app. But as far as I know, there is nothing equivalent to those projects.

I found some really nice project, which are not yet complete but are a good start:

- https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-oauth2-server
- https://github.com/domenic/restify-oauth2

In addition, I came across a nice article that suggests a nice way to deal with authentication in nodeJS. https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/ and a similar answer to a questtion on stackoverflow. [Auth between a website and self-owned API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793902/auth-between-a-website-and-self-owned-api/20804905?noredirect=1#comment35537435_20804905)

From what I understood, expressJwt guards our api's and basically will validate the access token sent by the user. But I'd like to go a step further, and associate a token with app specific scopes, in a similar way that one would do with the OAuth2.0 protocol. So for example, I would like to assign a write, read etc. scopes and have expressJwt check if the user's token has the required scopes to access as specific API endpoint.

I would be grateful if you could provide me with some suggestions about how to deal with this topic.

Comment: I'd definitely go for tokens rather than cookies. This will save you from the hell that CSRF attacks are.

Comment: @m_vdbeek thanks! It's been quite a few time that I moved to the tokens approach. I just want to do what I was would do in .NET. i.e. protecting API endpoints by assinging specific scopes, just as the OAUTH 2.0 protocol suggests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to generate a token with such claims. This could be in an API or some other place:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var claims = {
  name: user.name
  can_write: true,
  can_post_timeline: false
};

var token = jwt.sign(claims, 'my-super-secret');
```

Then, to validate you will do something like this:

```
var jwt = require('express-jwt');

app.use(jwt({secret: 'my-super-secret'}));

function require_time_line_access (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.user.can_post_timeline) return res.send(401);
  next();
}

app.post('/timeline', 
  require_time_line_access,
  function(req, res) {
    //do timeline stuff
  });
```

`express-jwt` validates the signature of the token, expiration and few other things. If everything is okay it puts the decoded token in `req.user`, and if is not okay it returns 401.

`require_time_line_access` is a middleware that ensure the user has this claim, if it doesnt it returns 401. You can put this middleware in every endpoint that needs this claim.

Comment: Wow! thanks a lot. I've got one my question, and  I would appreciate if you could help me. Basically, I want to separate the authentication/authorization module from the main app. So I'm thinking to move the token generation logic to a separate server or probably even the authentication mechanism on its own server, as well. In essence, I'll have the Identity Provider and Authorization server on individual servers. So the browser will first hit the authorization server, which it turn will contact the authentication server if the user is not authenticated. Finally, it will return a token....

Comment: ...which the client can use when hitting the APIs. I'm just curious if this sort of workflow is feasible, considering that express-jwt will use the same secret value

Comment: Yes, of course. If you handle the two ends (the two servers) this is okay. If not, remember that you can also generate JWTs with an asymmetric key both modules I mention in this answer support this, in that case the server that generates the token has a private key and the one that needs to validates has only the public key. This is what google does with JWTs. https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#validatinganidtoken